# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello below I got code that draws a Polyline, and gets segments colors from a list. Its working fine, I want to remove this Polyline when I click a button, I keep getting this error whenever I call the function: *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of null"*

Code:

```
var map;
var PathStyle;

function initialize() {

var mapDiv = document.getElementById('testerbuttons');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'click', showAlert);

$.getJSON("http://whatever.com/test.php", function(roads){
var routeseg=Object.keys(roads).length;
var arr1=[];
var filarr=[]
var router=[];
var colorarray=[]
for (i = 0; i < routeseg; i++) { 
var x=0;
    $.each(roads[i], function(key, value){
    (filarr[x]=value); 
    arr1[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(filarr[3], filarr[4]);
    colorarray[i]=filarr[5];
    x=x+1;
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length-1; i++) {
PathStyle = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: [arr1[i], arr1[i+1]],
     strokeColor:colorarray[i],
     strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 8,
    map: map
    });
}});


  var mapOptions = {
zoom: 20,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0085, 30.9825)};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);}

 function showAlert(){
    PathStyle.setMap(null);
    }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Note that `PathStyle` is overwritten in every iteration of the loop ?

Comment: Yes, I had to do this to give each segment a color... Is there another way ?

Comment: Where are you calling deleter from?

Comment: from an html button, its working, I had a console.log

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: done, I added the full code

Comment: That isn't complete (or Minimal).  Please provide data and any HTML/CSS required to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep references to all the segments if you want to hide all of them (and not just the last).  You also need to make the PathStyle variable not local to whatever the function is that is creating the line.

Comment: how do i keep reference?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue